# Magento2 extensions installation from gitHub

Tags: magento, github, plugins, composer-php, magento2

I want to modify one extension from public `Github` repository (fork) and install it to my Magento2 via `composer`.

Extensions stored here [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples). Really, i need only one `sample-external-links`. I tried many times to configure composer.json in my Magento2 root, but it doesn't work , i receive errors:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "https://api.github.com/repos/magento/magento2-samples/sample-external-links" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

How to configure composer to install only 1 package from some repository like that?

my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.0",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/sample-bundle-all": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {       "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/sample-external-links"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

Comment: why you don't download the package then put it in app/code folder without composer?

Comment: is it still actual?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

Change

```
"repositories": [
    {       "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/sample-external-links"
    }
],
```

to

```
"repositories": [
        {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@github.com:samples/sample-external-links.git"
    }
    ],
```

And then add your module on require:

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.2.5",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "yourvendor/sample-external-links": "dev-master", // your module should add here
  },
```